# Getting MonoTouch Navigation Depth

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using a variety of these commands to navigate my app:

```
NavigationController.PushViewController( ... );
NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated( ... );
```

In my app it's possible wander around and get a bit deep in pushed view controllers.  I want to popup a message when they get more than 15-20 levels deep.  I can add my own counter, but is there a way to determine the depth of the Navigation Controller's stack?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated) {
    base.ViewWillAppear( animated );

    int DEPTH = NavigationController.ViewControllers.Count();
    if ( DEPTH > 15 ) {
        MessageManager.MessageBox("Warning: You have navigated " 
               + DEPTH 
               + " levels forward into the model.  Navigating too many levels can be confusing for many users.");
    }
}
```